# How to make QWidget contents scrollable in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt4

First, I started using PyQt few hours ago.
So far so good - im writing rss client to familiarize myself with PyQt 
I got `QApplication`, `QMainWindow` and two custom widgets.
First custom widget is:

```
class RssItem(QWidget):
    __pyqtSignals__ = ("articleViewed(bool)",
                       "articleOpened(bool)",
                       "articleMarkedGood(bool)")

    def __init__(self, title, date, parent = None):
        super(RssItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initWidget(title, date)

    def initWidget(self, title, date):
        title = QLabel(title)
        date = QLabel(date)
        titleBox = QHBoxLayout()
        titleBox.addWidget(title)
        titleBox.addWidget(date)
        self.setLayout(titleBox)
```

That displays (for now) title and date in single row
Second one accepts array of `RssItem` widgets and display them in vertical list:

```
class ItemsList(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, items, parent=None):
        super(ItemsList, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initWidget(items)

    def initWidget(self, items):
        listBox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        for item in items:
            listBox.addWidget(item)
            listBox.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(listBox)
```

How do I make this list scrollable? 
Keep in mid I'm planing to have multiple `ItemList`'s in one window each should have it's own scrollbar.

Main app function as for now is only for testing these 2 widgets:

```
class MainApp(Qt.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(args)
        self.addWidgets()
        self.exec_()

    def addWidgets(self):
        self.window = MainWindow()


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("ok")
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle("Smart Rss")
        items=[]
        for x in range(0, 200):
            items.append(RssItem("Title no %s" % x, "2000-1-%s" %x))
        self.setCentralWidget(ItemsList(items))
        self.show()
```

---

EDIT:Getting closer, changed `ItemList.initWidget` to

```
def initWidget(self, items):
    scroll= QScrollArea(self)
    wrap = QWidget(self)
    listBox = QVBoxLayout(self)
    for item in items:
        listBox.addWidget(item)
        listBox.addStretch(1)
    wrap.setLayout(listBox)
    scroll.setWidget(wrap)
```

But now I cant figure out how to make `QScrollArea` fill all available space and auto resize when it's changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)` like in here:

```
def initWidget(self, items):
    listBox = QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.setLayout(listBox)

    scroll = QScrollArea(self)
    listBox.addWidget(scroll)
    scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    scrollContent = QWidget(scroll)

    scrollLayout = QVBoxLayout(scrollContent)
    scrollContent.setLayout(scrollLayout)
    for item in items:
        scrollLayout.addWidget(item)
    scroll.setWidget(scrollContent)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a note, I think you might be setting the layout for scrollContent and listbox twice

Comment: @user1650538 Probably, I don't remember TBH :) Feel free to edit the answer if you verify that it's indeed being set twice ;)